# Does Spring Session require servlet 3.0?

Tags: spring, servlet-3.0, spring-session, servlet-2.5

I'm looking at using the Spring Session library (http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) and was wondering does using this API require a servlet 3.0 container? Will it work/run on a servlet 2.5 container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet 2.5 is minimum requirement to use Spring Session.

Read the issue and its comments which explains about the minimum requirement of servlet for spring session.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/119

Another related issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/111

Both the issues have been fixed :-)